# firebase , just read public and disallowed write?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I want to just allow read and not allow to write.

I try this:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

is it enough to my purpose?

Comment: yes check this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#sample-rules

Comment: and go to private tab

Comment: Private tab, disallowed every thing, i want to read just by auth users, and Write by nobody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Your Quetion I am worked on It and i have Little bit Hack for it.

```
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
match /{allPaths=**} {
   allow read;
   allow write: if false == true;
  }
 }
}
```

Hope you liked it. it was successfully works on me.